# Insert licence in Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, dependencies, jxbrowser

I've made some tests using JxBrowser and intend to add it to my academic project.

However, it is a Maven project, which I develop using the Netbeans IDE, and although I added the TeamDev JxBrowser repository, the JxBrowser dependency in the `pom.xml` file and tried to manually insert the `licence.jar` that I acquire, it is failing to execute properly.

Maybe the issue is the fact that I am downloading the library by its repository and the license is a separated file.

I also upload an attachment that illustrates my problem and the message displayed when I execute the method that uses JxBrowser; it says that I don't have a valid license, although I manually inserted my `licence.jar` as a local dependency.

Could you please help me through this? What should I do? I really have high hopes about using JxBrowser in my project.

[image: Netbeans Display]

Comment: I do not see a message that says "_don't have a valid license_" in your screenshot. Where exactly did you put `licence.jar` to? Can you add the relevant parts of your POM to your question.

Comment: I've posted below the error messages and some extract of my pom file, the licence.jar is in the folder that is in the pom file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the licence.jar (it's just a zip file), you will get META-INF/teamdev.licenses file
Put it in

> src/main/java/resources/META-INF/teamdev.licenses

Comment: I tried that, however it can't recognize properly the licence.jar, althought it appears like a 'Dependency' in the project netbeans folder, and in it properties it said that my licence is still valid.

Comment: @gdeluccas can you show me the path of teamdev.licenses file in your project? If you use netbeans config, the project cannot be packaged by maven.

Comment: the original licence.jar file is in C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TesteTCC\licence.jar, which is the folder of my netbeans project; after I inserted it, it resides C:\Users\Gabriel\.m2\repository\mylibid\licence\1.0\licence-1.0.jar

Comment: tha path is C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TesteTCC\pom.xml

Comment: Is there C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TesteTCC\src\main\java folder?

Comment: Yes there is, and I already tried extract the jar file into it, like you said; then I pointed the dependency and the repository into it, but the problem still persisted.

Comment: Even when I don't point it to, just extract in the folder you said it persists, I'd like to understand what it means that the "The POM for mylibid:licence:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available" when I compile the project...

Comment: please remove the licence jar in pom.xml, too. If it cannot run I will send you an example project that I have run successful

Comment: I tried that, and now I got the message that no valid licence was found, you only put the licence along with the source codes and it works? with JxBrowser? Thanks for the patient yelliver, it would be helpful if you could send me your example.

Comment: @gdeluccas this is my runnable simplest maven project, https://github.com/yelliver/demoJxbrowser

Comment: Now it works! I place the licence file in "Other Sourcers", like your simple project; thank you @yelliver.

Comment: @gdeluccas congrats! I am working on a project that uses Jxbrowser, too. So if you have any problem on Jxbrowser, I can help you

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I discovered that I wasn't referencing the proper jar file, but the one in the com.teamdev.jxbrowser repository (default trial version), not the one that I have in my local machine; in that case, after the 30 days trial expired, I am not able to use the Jxbrowser anymore, even thought I have the proper jar file.
So, I still have the same problem, I am uploading the error message in netbeans and some parts of my pom.xml file that references to the licence.jar in my computer.
I also have tried manually inserted the jar again, not obtaining any success.

```
<repository>
   <id>mylibid</id>
   <url>file:${basedir}</url>
</repository>
<dependency>
  <groupId>mylibid</groupId>
  <artifactId>licence</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

[image: NETBEANS COMPILING/EXECUTING MESSAGES]

I manually inserted the `licence.jar` file in a new dependency, but on the artifact's `<groupId>` I put the `com.teamdev.jxbrowser` (the same on as the JxBrowser dependency on the `pom.xml` file); and NetBeans automatically linked the licence with the `.jars` in the library.

Hope it could help someone that might have some similar doubt.