# How to add licenses to Maven dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have license files and URLs, I need to add these URLs and txt file licenses to their respective dependencies.

I am trying to do with `license-maven-plugin`, but these goals are only adding third-party libs and download licenses.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <version>1.51</version>
</dependency>
```

The license is http://www.bouncycastle.org/licence.html

I need to add this license URL to the dependency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert licence in Maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618276/insert-licence-in-maven-dependency)

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk Not a duplicate.

Comment: I have some dependencies along with license files, I don't want to generate and reports, I need to add dependency along with URL(license). Any possible way...